# Given a point and a plane, how do I translate the point to match the plane when the plane scales without scaling the point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, matrix

Given a plane with a matrix that both translates it and scales it, I have an overlay point that can only translate but not scale and has to stay on the same point on the plane. If the plane is translated using the following transform for example:

```
matrix(1,0,0,1,33,33);
```

I can just match it on the point.

But, if the matrix looks like this:

```
matrix(1.5,0,0,1.5,33,33);
```

I can't just match it because the size of the point will scale.

How do I find a translate that will move the point to match the plane without scaling the point? 
Sorry if it seems obvious, I'm a bit mathematically challenged.

Comment: That's for mathematica, which is a specific programming language that I am not using.

Comment: oops haha, what I meant was that yo should check out the math stack exchange, since you're problem seems to be more math related than coding related.  http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

A point has no size, it is just a position. A scale + rotate is a transform between coordinates, so the scaling is actually a scaling of the distances to the origin, rather than of the object itself. For a rectangle, that means applying the transform to each corner. For a point, it means applying the (whole) transform to the point.

What makes you think the point would be scaled?

If you just want to apply the rotation transform and not the scaling transform, then assuming your matrix definition is the CSS matrix (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function), then the list is a,b,c,d,tx,ty. A rotation is given as

```
[cos(a) -sin(a) sin(a) cos(a) 0 0]
```

So if you use the a,b pair and the c,d pair you can normalize to calculate the rotation angle by itself without scaling.